# How to stop timer at the touch of cell and start the timer at the time of releasing the cell touch

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone .I have a small doubt that is I have a timer and uitableView when we click on cell(i.e.touches begin) on table-view.I want to stop the timer and when we release the touch in cell(i.e.touches end) it will start the timer.How can we do this? If any body knows this, please help me.Can we do this gestures.If possible can somebody enlighten me how to.Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

start the timer in `– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

stop  the timer in `– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`